# Grouping Data in excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am unable to group or create bin in excel. It gives me the error like "cannot group this selection", even the data in the table is in value format. I am using ms excel 2021.

[image: error image]

[image: The charEven though the age column in raw table is in value format, but when I am addding it to pivot table, it is acting as textt I want to create.]

Comment: **Age** (Numbers) are left aligned which means they are formatted as text in the source data, you need to transform them to numbers. In Excel Texts are by default left aligned while numbers are right aligned. To make them numbers in the source data, place `0` in some empty cells, copy it and use paste special as values to add as an operation, it would convert to numbers if it doesnt work, may be it has some non printable characters or blank spaces, which needs to be cleaned.